# Is there only one catkin_ws can be active?

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone!
Suppose I have two ros projects to develop at the same time, A and B.
B use some exported files of A.
But I can't source A and B devel/setup.bash at the same time...
And I don't want to put A and B in one catkin_ws.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287429/is-there-only-one-catkin_ws-can-be-active-?/) by [zcm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33932/zcm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2018-04-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is where you create multiple workspace overlays (i.e. `catkin_ws`s) and use [workspace chaining](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/workspace_overlaying#Chaining_catkin_workspaces).

Depending on wether you use `catkin_make` or `catkin tools`, the workflow is a bit different. I'll demonstrate this with `catkin_make`.

1. create your first workspace, i.e. where you put your package A, as you normally would:

   ```
    $ mkdir ~/catkin_ws_A
       $ cd ~/catkin_ws_A
    $ <PUT PACKAGE A IN HERE>
       $ source /opt/ros/<ROSDISTRO>/setup.bash
    $ catkin_make
   ```
2. create another workspace for package

   ```
    $ mkdir ~/catkin_ws_B
       $ cd ~/catkin_ws_B
    $ <PUT PACKAGE B IN HERE>
       $ source ~/catkin_ws_A/devel/setup.bash   <----- This is the important difference!
    $ catkin_make
   ```

Now, you can compile both workspaces independently and B has Access to A (but not the other way around!). Also note that you have to compile first `catkin_ws_A` and then `catkin_ws_B` if you change something in package `A`, thus that it takes effect.

Note that you have to `source ~/catkin_ws_B/devel/setup.bash` to accomplish this. Just sourcing `caktin_ws_A` will be your regular one workspace layout.

There are some side-effects regarding build artifacts, thus I'd recommend you read the wiki page linked above (section 4) carefully. But all in all, this works pretty well.

---

**EDIT**

When you already have two workspaces, make sure to delete any `build`/`devel`/`install`/`logs` folders in `caktin_ws_B`, as well as the top-Level `CMakeLists.txt`. You need to create the chaining from a clean workspace. And don't to forget to `source ~/catkin_ws_A/devel/setup.bash` before  calling `catkin_make` in `caktin_ws_B` in the same terminal.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zcm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33932/zcm/) on 2018-04-04**:
Thanks for your reply! When I first source ~/catkin_ws_A/devel/setup.bash, $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH shows ~/catkin_ws_A/src : /opt/ros/kinetic/share,  so I can rosrun nodes in A.
But when I later source ~/catkin_ws_B/devel/setup.bash,  $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH shows ~/catkin_ws_B/src : /opt/ros/kinetic/share ?

**Comment by [zcm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33932/zcm/) on 2018-04-04**:
I can rosrun nodes in B after source ~/catkin_ws_B/devel/setup.bash, but these nodes import modules from   A, the $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH doesn't include ~/catkin_ws_A/src then, so can't find these modules...   I don't know what I did wrong. Thanks!

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-04-04**:
see edit above.

**Comment by [zcm](https://answers.ros.org/users/33932/zcm/) on 2018-04-04**:
It works! Thank you very much!